# Micro Framework Lumen - Seguridad Token

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt, lumen

He creado un api rest en **Lumen**, ya lo he subido a mi hosting y todo funciona perfectamente. El tema es que no tiene seguridad, me refiero a que no cuenta con una "session" por así decirlo cuando se logean, he estado investigando y he encontrado **JWT** pero no he encontrado algún tutorial de como implementarlo con Lumen, también he visto **Passport** que es un solución para **Laravel**, pero en Lumen no funciona.

**¿Ustedes sabrán como puedo generar mi token y brindar la seguridad en mi login?**

Comment: Create una clase para generar / validar los tokens. La añades como librería al framework. Luego manejas JWT a traves del rooting, directamente o con un middleware.

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a probarlo.